# How to create File from FileDescriptor?

Tags: java, file, file-descriptor

Given a `FileDescriptor` object, is it possible to create a `File` from it somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not easily, if at all. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileDescriptor.html):

> Instances of the file descriptor class serve as an opaque handle to the underlying machine-specific structure

IFF your program will only run on a specific operating system, you could potentially extract information from the private `fd` field that is held within `FileDescriptor`.

For example, on Linux you could use that along with the process ID to access the `/proc/PID/fd` directory (or write JNI to access that information directly).

That is, of course, not portable to other operating systems. And it may or may not be possible to do the same thing on those other systems.